# How to Know When the User Opens An Android Application

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to know if there is a way to know when a user opens my `Android` application. Please specify the answer in `Kotlin`, as I do not know Java.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the app opening time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know the `time stamp` when user opens the app, then you handle this inside your `Application` class. Because when user opens your app `Application` class definitely instantiated before any `activity`. Look :

```
 class MyApplication: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
        // save this timeStamp in know the app opening time.
    }
}
```

If you are using custom `Application` class then make sure you have declared `android:name=".MyApplication"` in `<application>...</application>` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: I appreciate this comment. It might be helpful for me in the future. But all I want to do is to  check when the app is opened by the user, not get the time.

Comment: @TheProCoder, you will surely know when your launcher activity starts. In `onCreate`, you can then do whatever you want. The launcher activity would be declared in your manifest.

Comment: Yes, that was months ago. I don't know how my past self could of not seen that! Thanks for bringing this to my attention! 